# Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'class Template7

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

I'm following this tutorial to make an app w/ Framework7-Vue.
http://blog.toast38coza.me/building-a-mobile-app-with-vuejs-cordova-webpack-and-framework-7/

For some reason, I see a blank screen once I've copied all the code and installed everything.  I get no errors during compile time.  I get the following error once the app is running in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'class Template7 {
  constructor(template) {
    const t = this;
    t.template = template;

    function getCom...<omitted>...
}'
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///29:381)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///29:557)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:879)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
    at fn (app.js:86)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///21:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:826)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
    at fn (app.js:86)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///10:3)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use latest framework7, use version 1.x, just like:

you can find version `npm info framework7`

`yarn upgrade framework7@1.6.4` or `npm upgrade framework7@1.6.4`

Answer (score 0):

use propTypes example:

```
User.propTypes={
  load: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```